# Issue in adding label when connector type is defined in jsplumb

Tags: javascript, html, jsplumb

I am using instance.bind("connection", function (connInfo) {} ) to create a connection using jsplumb. During the connection I want to edit the connector type and add label to the connection. I am able to either add a label or edit the connector type but not both. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

js block:

```
instance.bind("connection", function (connInfo) {
// listens for connection anywhere on topology
    var sourceId = connInfo.sourceId;
    var targetId = connInfo.targetId;

    if (sourceId == targetId) {
    // to edit connector type
    connInfo.connection.setConnector([ "Flowchart", { stub:20, gap: 10, cornerRadius: 10} ]);     
    // To add label.          
    connInfo.connection.getOverlay("sourceLabel").setLabel("bar");
    console.log(connInfo);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set connector style and label while adding endpoints like this:

```
            jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(".yourselector"), {
                anchor: "Right",
                isSource:true,
                isTarget:false,
                connector:"Bezier",
                endpoint: "Dot",
                paintStyle:{ fillStyle:"white", outlineColor:"blue", 
                            outlineWidth:1, radius:8 },
                hoverPaintStyle:{ fillStyle:"lightblue" },
                connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:"grey", lineWidth:3 },
                connectorHoverStyle:{ lineWidth:3 },
                overlays:[ [ "Label", {label:"FOO", id:"label"}] ] 
            });
```

Your connector will be formatted like this when you drag it from source endpoint manually. You can set different styles for different endpoints.